# Мню бургер работает только в шапке сайта, из середины страницы сначала кидает в шапку и потом заходит в меню

Tags: javascript

Извините за столь странный вопрос, но буду признателен за помощь и подсказки как исправить это. Проект на гитхабе https://github.com/AlexandrHan/work , как я понимаю вся загвоздка в javascript, а я в нем пока не понимаю нифига. Когда листаю на мобильном сайт и посреди страницы нажимаю на меню то меня кидает в шапку сайта, а потом только при следующем клике открывает меню. Заметил новый момент, когда на мобильном скролю вниз, адресная строка браузера становится маленькой и при клике на менюшку отправлчет в шапку, а если начать скролить вверх и после этого нажать на меню, то откроется меню

var mobileMenuOutsideClick = function() {

```
    $(document).click(function (e) {
    var container = $("#fh5co-offcanvas, .js-fh5co-nav-toggle");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {

        if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas') ) {

            $('body').removeClass('offcanvas');
            $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
            
        }
    
        
    }
    });

};


var offcanvasMenu = function() {

    $('#page').prepend('<div id="fh5co-offcanvas" />');
    $('#page').prepend('<a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-white"><i></i></a>');
    var clone1 = $('.menu-1 > ul').clone();
    $('#fh5co-offcanvas').append(clone1);
    var clone2 = $('.menu-2 > ul').clone();
    $('#fh5co-offcanvas').append(clone2);

    $('#fh5co-offcanvas .has-dropdown').addClass('offcanvas-has-dropdown');
    $('#fh5co-offcanvas')
        .find('li')
        .removeClass('has-dropdown');

    // Hover dropdown menu on mobile
    $('.offcanvas-has-dropdown').mouseenter(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this
            .addClass('active')
            .find('ul')
            .slideDown(500, 'easeOutExpo');             
    }).mouseleave(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .removeClass('active')
            .find('ul')
            .slideUp(500, 'easeOutExpo');               
    });


    $(window).resize(function(){

        if ( $('body').hasClass('offcanvas') ) {

            $('body').removeClass('offcanvas');
            $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
            
        }
    });
};


var burgerMenu = function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.js-fh5co-nav-toggle', function(event){
        var $this = $(this);


        if ( $('body').hasClass('overflow offcanvas') ) {
            $('body').removeClass('overflow offcanvas');
        } else {
            $('body').addClass('overflow offcanvas');
        }
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        event.preventDefault();

    });
};

var fullHeight = function() {

    if ( !isMobile.any() ) {
        $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
        });
    }

};



var contentWayPoint = function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.animate-box').waypoint( function( direction ) {

        if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated-fast') ) {
            
            i++;

            $(this.element).addClass('item-animate');
            setTimeout(function(){

                $('body .animate-box.item-animate').each(function(k){
                    var el = $(this);
                    setTimeout( function () {
                        var effect = el.data('animate-effect');
                        if ( effect === 'fadeIn') {
                            el.addClass('fadeIn animated-fast');
                        } else if ( effect === 'fadeInLeft') {
                            el.addClass('fadeInLeft animated-fast');
                        } else if ( effect === 'fadeInRight') {
                            el.addClass('fadeInRight animated-fast');
                        } else {
                            el.addClass('fadeInUp animated-fast');
                        }

                        el.removeClass('item-animate');
                    },  k * 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
                });
                
            }, 100);
            
        }

    } , { offset: '85%' } );
};


var dropdown = function() {

    $('.has-dropdown').mouseenter(function(){

        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .find('.dropdown')
            .css('display', 'block')
            .addClass('animated-fast fadeInUpMenu');

    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this
            .find('.dropdown')
            .css('display', 'none')
            .removeClass('animated-fast fadeInUpMenu');
    });

};


var goToTop = function() {

    $('.js-gotop').on('click', function(event){
        
        event.preventDefault();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('html').offset().top
        }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        
        return false;
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var $win = $(window);
        if ($win.scrollTop() > 200) {
            $('.js-top').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.js-top').removeClass('active');
        }

        if ( $win.scrollTop() > 100 ) {
            $('.fh5co-nav').addClass('scrolled');
        } else {
            $('.fh5co-nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        }

    });

};


// Loading page
var loaderPage = function() {
    $(".fh5co-loader").fadeOut("slow");
};


var counterWayPoint = function() {
    if ($('#fh5co-counter').length > 0 ) {
        $('#fh5co-counter').waypoint( function( direction ) {
                                    
            if( direction === 'down' && !$(this.element).hasClass('animated') ) {
                setTimeout( counter , 400);                 
                $(this.element).addClass('animated');
            }
        } , { offset: '90%' } );
    }
};

var sliderMain = function() {
    
    $('#fh5co-slider-wrwap .flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        directionNav: true,
        start: function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.slider-text').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
                $('.flex-active-slide').find('.slider-text').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            }, 500);
        },
        before: function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.slider-text').removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
                $('.flex-active-slide').find('.slider-text').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            }, 500);
        }

    });

    $('#fh5co-slider-wrwap .flexslider .slides > li').css('height', $(window).height());    
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#fh5co-slider-wrwap .flexslider .slides > li').css('height', $(window).height());    
    });

    
};
```

Comment: битая ссылка на гит, исправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо поправил